# What is the vertical offset of geopotential height from ellipsoidal height in GFS?

Tags: gfs, coordinate-system

I would like to compare NOAA GFS (Global Forecast System) geopotential height from ASL and GTOPO30.

However, I cannot find vertical offset information in GFS geopotential height. Does anyone know where it is located?
(And, I assume that GTOPO30 is in the geometric height from ASL ... is that correct?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer

Geopotential height of ground or water surface is available as a variable ([UCAR variable inventory](https://rda.ucar.edu/datasets/ds084.1/#metadata/detailed.html?_do=y)).
It is called 'orography' if you read the file with cfgrib. Somehow it did not appear in variable inventory when read with pygrib ...

Alternatively, I could have used [MetPy](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.calc.geopotential_to_height.html?highlight=height#metpy.calc.geopotential_to_height).